# Page Inspector in ASP.NET MVC not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to open razor view templates in Page Inspector mode and those are not shown. What I get instead is the error `The resource cannot be found.`

My path to open the View Page is `View/Admin/Login.cshtml`

Earlier I have used the controller with the name `AdminController` but now I am using the controller with a different name. What I have done is divide the `AdminController` into multiple controllers in order to ease out things. I have one named `LoginController`.

When I run the project all views are working fine, but not in page inspector mode.

How can this page inspector problem  be resolved?

Comment: When you moved logic to another controller, did you also move the view to matching folder name. For example if your action method Login has logic such as return View(), it would first look for the folder named same as controller and then towards share etc. So you would have to move the view to folder named login, or return view like this return View("~/Views/YourArea/YourController/YourView.aspx");

Answer (score 0):

Check following place of your code:

```
webconfig
    <appSettings> 
      <add key="loginUrl" value="[ControllerName]/[LoginActionName]" /> ...
```

if it is still render wrong, then add following to system.web in web config too(if you use Form Authenticate):

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="[ControllerName]/[LoginActionName]" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
```